# PHP assign variable definition from a string

Tags: php

Let's say I have a file "`English.txt`" containing these lines :

```
$_LANG["accountinfo"] = "Account Information";
$_LANG["accountstats"] = "Account Statistics";
```

**Note** : the file extension is `.txt` and there is **nothing** I can do to change that. There is no opening PHP tag (`<?php`) or anything, *just* those lines, period.

I need to extract and actually get the `$_LANG` array declared from these lines. How do I do that? Simply `include`ing the file echoes every line, so I do

```
ob_start();
include '/path/to/English.txt';
$str = ob_get_clean();
```

Now, if I call `eval` on that string, I get an `syntax error, unexpected $end`. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: getting unexpected end like that probably means there's an unterminated string in the file.

Comment: I think for each line parsing two words between quotes (for eg, "accountinfo", "Account Information") and storing in an array is another solution that you can use. You cannot include file that does not indicate it is a php file.

Comment: It seems to work fine for me... at least with these two lines.

Comment: @Marc B. no, this file gets included in some protected code just fine, but I need to include another file just as this one somewhere else and I don't know how the protected code does it....

Comment: @user482: you can include any kind of file you want. Until the PHP interpreter sees a `<?php` string go by, included files are treated as plain text, regardless of file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eval(file_get_contents('English.txt'));
```

however, be sure NOBODY can change English.txt, it could be dangerous!

Comment: that file is the language file, and trust me, I sure am NOT the author of this atrocity! I just have to use it... anyhow. I'm not sure why this works and not with output buffering but, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that you should use `file_get_contents` instead of `include` with output buffering.  Since it contains no `<?php` tag, there is no need to run it through the script processor.

The following works perfectly in my tests:

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents("English.txt");
eval($contents);
var_dump($_LANG);
```

As one of the comments said, if you do the above and *still* get an error, then your file does **NOT** contain exactly/only those lines.  Make sure the file is actually syntax compliant.

As has been  mentioned, you should really use `eval` only as a last resort, and **only** if the file is as safe to execute as any code you write.  In other words, it must not be editable by the outside world.